# Prolongation/Restriction Operator in Multigrid

Tags: interpolation, multigrid, poisson

In Multigrid, using Poisson's equation, does the equality below **always** hold regardless of what type of boundary conditions you use?
$$
R= c\cdot I^T, \text{ for some constant }c
$$
where $R$ and $I$ are the restriction and interpolation operator. Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a question whether the condition holds or not. You choose $R$ so that it's a multiple of $I^T$ because you *want* the condition to hold. You want the condition to hold because that's the only way you can ensure that the multigrid operator is symmetric and amenable to, say, being a preconditioner for CG.

Comment: Ugh. My restriction operator wasn't handling inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions properly. So I wrote it separately...Meaning that as of now I have no $c$ s.t. the equality holds. Does this mean I'll have to reconfigure everything?

Comment: Probably. You will also note that if you were to naively build restriction and prolongation operators as if you wanted them to represent an interpolation between spaces (which I imagine is what you did) that they will not respect the equality. That's why we call them restriction/prolongation and not up-/down-interpolation or similar.

Comment: Well i used bilinear interpolation and full weighting. I worked out a few cases by hand and made note of how the matrix changed depending on the size of the discretization. I did the same thing for homogeneous Dirichlet bc and it worked out fine, but as soon as I started messing with inhomogeneous, everything went awry.